# Extending Symfony 2 request service?

Tags: symfony

I'm following [How to Override any Part of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/override.html) page on Symfony 2 website. This is interesting:

> You can set the parameter holding the service's class name to your own
>   class by setting it in app/config/config.yml. This of course is only
>   possible if the class name is defined as a parameter in the service
>   config of the bundle containing the service.

So i looked at `/vendor/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config` and i found that `session.xml` is defining `%session.class%` parameter, so it should be easy to extend Symfony `Session` class with something like:

```php
namespace Acme\HelloBundle\Component\HttpFoundation;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;

class ExtendedSession extends Session
{
    public function setSuccessFlashText($text, array params = array())
    {
       parent::setFlash('success', $this->getTranslator()->trans($text, $params);
    }
}
```

I din't tested this yet. But how can i do the same with `request` special service? I'd like to adding some convenient shortcuts in order to make my code easier to read.

I found this in `services.xml` file:

```xml
    <!--
        If you want to change the Request class, modify the code in
        your front controller (app.php) so that it passes an instance of
        YourRequestClass to the Kernel.
        This service definition only defines the scope of the request.
        It is used to check references scope.
    -->
    <service id="request" scope="request" synthetic="true" />
```

Here is my `app.php`. How i'm supposed to pass an instance of my custom request class?

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$kernel->handle(Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Comment: `web/app.php` - you don't have such? O_o

Comment: @thecatontheflat lol :D i was looking at `/app` folder... i'm going to update the question then.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, it is simple.

In your `app.php` just pass instance of `YourRequest` instead of default:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
//require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

use src\YourCompany\YourBundle\YourRequest;

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
//$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);
$kernel->handle(YourRequest::createFromGlobals())->send();
```

Just ensure, that you extended from default `Request` in `YourRequest` class.

Should work without additional service definitions.

---

According to comments, there are thoughts that this will cause problems with IDE autocompletion. In theory - it should not.

In your controller you just add `use` statement

```
use src\YourCompany\YourBundle\YourRequest;
```

And in action, where you pass `$request`, just define its class:

```
public function yourAction(YourRequest $request)
```

This will give you autocompletion.

In case if you want to get request as a service or from a controller, for IDE you can also define its class in comment doc:

```
    /** @var $request YourRequest */
    $request = $this->getRequest();
```

Comment: Mhm... seems so easy, i'll try! Then only bad thing of this, i suppose, is that you can't get IDE auto completition features...

Comment: You always can. Updated my answer

Comment: Please how to make our Request class available in tests? When using functional tests, my custom methods on my custom Request are unavailable. Please help...

Comment: @WaxCage more difficult, check Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client, request method. I think you can copy/paste this method and replace Request object by your.