# Symfony: changing the request base class and updating the test environment

Tags: php, symfony, request, phpunit

I have modified the base Request class of my application as explained in the [accepted answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823294/extending-symfony-2-request-service). It works very well, except when launching my functional tests, I get the following error:

> Controller `"My\Bundle\AppBundle\Controller\MyController::searchAction()"`
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$request" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non-optional argument after this one). (500 Internal Server Error)

Indeed there is no `app_test.php` controller used. I was hoping it could be done in the `createCient()` function of my `WebTestCase` base class, but how?

```
/**
 * Creates a Client.
 *
 * @param array $options An array of options to pass to the createKernel class
 * @param array $server  An array of server parameters
 *
 * @return Client A Client instance
 */
protected static function createClient(array $options = array(), array $server = array())
{
    static::bootKernel($options);

    $client = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('test.client');
    $client->setServerParameters($server);

    return $client;
}
```

- Symfony 2.6.9 is used.

**[Edit 21 September 2017]:**

I have to do the following when migrating to Symfony 3.3:

`config_test.yml`:

```
parameters:
    test.client.class: My\Bundle\AppBundle\Tests\Client

services:
    test.client:
        class: '%test.client.class%'
        arguments: ['@kernel', '%test.client.parameters%', '@test.client.history', '@test.client.cookiejar']
```

Comment: If you redefine the service yourself, don't forget to add `shared: false`. See [default configuration](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/test.xml#L14) to get a [new instance each time](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/shared.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you have to override the class for `test.client` which, by default, uses `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Client`.

Something like:

```
<parameters>
    <parameter name="test.client.class">My\Bundle\AppBundle\Test\Client</parameter>
</parameters>
```

First, take a look at the base class `Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Client`.

If you look at the `request` method of this class you will find this:

```
public function request(/* ... */)
{
    // ...
    $this->internalRequest = new Request($uri, $method, $parameters, $files, $this->cookieJar->allValues($uri), $server, $content);

    $this->request = $this->filterRequest($this->internalRequest);
    // ...
}
```

Now look at the `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client` and the `filterRequest` method:

```
protected function filterRequest(DomRequest $request)
{
     $httpRequest = Request::create($request->getUri(), $request->getMethod(), $request->getParameters(), $request->getCookies(), $request->getFiles(), $request->getServer(), $request->getContent());

    // ...
}
```

Here is where the actual magic happens. This is the method you have to override if you need to have a different request object.

Edit:

This `$httpRequest` is then going to be serialized and unserialized. Just take a look at the `getScript` method of `Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Client` class.

Comment: Thanks for the hints @awons! I will modify my question to add details about what I did exactly. Now everything works as expected and there is no more "short-cut" functions in my controllers.

Comment: for me it was a little confusing where to add those configuration lines with **test.client.class** - its configuration file services.xxx (in my case services.yml). Its the **parameters** attribute right at the beginning of file.